# When I try to install signed apk then it give me error "Application not installed"

Tags: android, apk

I was running app on my devices from Android studio direct it was working fine. Then I have uninstalled that unsigned APK from Application manager. But now when I am trying to install signed APK from SD card then it give me error "Application not installed". My device android version is 6.0.1. Not sure what's the problem. Tried every thing but same problem. Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Comment: have you uninstalled the application for all users ? If not then go to application manager and look into download section and scroll at the bottom. If your app is there then click and uninstall for all users.

Comment: Go in setting and check all app as well process for that app and if you found it than uninstall or stop it

Comment: I am not able to see my app in Application manager.

Comment: Could you able to install your unsigned apk from sd card?

Comment: Yes i am able to install

Answer (score 0):

1. Change application package name from `my.app.pack` into `my.app.pack.1`
2. Remove application/photos to increase memory.